# When a portal is burned out in ingress, how long until it's hackable again?

Tags: ingress

I just started playing and really needed to build inventory, so I found some portals close together, and walked a route to hack them over and over again.  After a little while the hacks started to fail and I got a message:

```
Portal burned out!  It may take significant time for the Portal to reset
```

How long is significant time?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According [to this site](http://ingressguide.com/portals/hacking/), the significant time is about **4 hours**.

Comment: Note that the burn-out timer counts from the first hack made! Meaning that if you hack at 8:00, 10:00, 10:05, 10:10, you will be able to hack again at 12:00. It's especially usable when you time it right, such as when a farm is planned and you hack the portals 4:20 hours ahead, which will give you almost 2x the hack amount!

Answer (score 15):

I've found that it is 4 hours *from the time of your first hack*. And it is triggered after you have successfully hacked the same portal four times in four hours (e.g. the fifth hack attempt will result in the "Portal burned  out!" message.

What I haven't determined is if this is a *rolling* four hour window.

For example, you hack Portal A at 08:00, then again later at 11:00, 11:05 and 11:10. If you attempt to hack Portal A again at 11:15, you'll get the "Portal burned out!" message. *But*, if you try again at 12:01, your hack will be successful (because four hours have elapsed since your *first* hack at 08:00.)

Now, if you attempt a sixth hack at 12:06, will it succeed because your "clock" has been reset at 12:00 and you now get a full four hacks in the next four hours? Or will it fail, because you have hacked the portal successfully four times since 11:00?

Further testing is needed.

Comment: Yes, it is a rolling 4 hours. Also good to mention that if you put a Heat Sink on the portal, the clock is reset instantly. So, if you hack 4 times, THEN place a HS on the portal, you can hack it again 4 times, without having to wait for burned out cool down.

Comment: Tested today on ingress prime, it is not a rolling 4 hours. Hacked an unmodded portal once at 9:30, then 3 times from 11:30-12. Portal burned out as expected. Hacked 4 more times from 1:45 to 2, which would not be possible with a rolling window as there had been 7 hacks between 11:30 and 2 (under 3 hours)

Answer (score 10):

The burn-out timer starts with your **first** hack as **mattozan** said and is

## **4 hours**.

---

### Hacking without mods

- Hacking at **08:00**, **11:00**, **11:05**, **11:10** will lock the portal until **12:00**.
  Hacking the portal at **12:01** will be successful.
- Hacking at **08:00** and then waiting until **12:00** will also result in refreshed timer and hack amount, meaning that 4 hacks will be available again, not only 3.

### Multi-hacks

- If a portal has, say, Common Multi-Hack (+4 hacks) and you hack it **3x** at **08:00**, **3x** at **09:00** and someone destroys the multihack, portal goes automatically into **burn-out** state.
- Likewise if a portal is burned-out and you place a Multi-Hack on it, you will be able to hack it immediately - the burn-out state gets **postponed**.

### Heatsink

- The *user who places* a heatsink on a portal can immediately hack again, moreover, the hackability is **completely refreshed** for *him* and *his* 4h burn-out timer restarts.
- See more info on [heatsink mod here](http://decodeingress.me/ingress-manual/ingress-items/portal-mods/heat-sink/)

### Protip: Farms

- Knowing all this can be 'exploited', especially when a **farm*** is planned.

> Say a farm with **RMH**, **2x RS** + turrets/force amps is planned at
>   **12:00**. All players will visit the place and hack all the portals **once at 09:00**. This will activate the burn-out timer, which refreshes portal's hackability at 13:00. At 12:00 players assemble
>   again, build up the farm and start hacking. Rare Multi-Hack gives +8
>   hacks = total **12 Hacks**. 1 hack was already made 3 hours ago, so it is
>   11 hacks left. After 55 minutes the 11 hacks are done and portal goes
>   into burn-out state, however it's by the time the burn-out timer kicks
>   in and refreshes the hackability of mentioned portals, giving players
>   **another 12 hacks**.
>
> ## = Total of 23 hacks with only 1 Rare Multi-Hack

#### *What is *a farm*

> A **Farm** is a local community's *'event'* at place with high density of portals. It's basically when a group of players levels up
>   portals for the sole reason of obtaining items from them. They keep on
>   hacking them until they burn them out, or until their inventories are
>   full. The farm is usually of a certain level and when mentioned in
>   chat, players use the term **F8 *there and there***. If there are some
>   multi-hacks or heat-sinks used, the notification could be as follows
>   **F8 2xVRMH VRHS**, or when 1 last player is needed **F8 1xR8 missing**.

---

**CMH**, **RMH**, **VRMH** = Common / Rare / Very Rare Multi-Hack
**RS** = Rare Shield
**VRHS** = Very Rare Heat Sink
**F8** = Farm of level 8 portals
**R8** = Resonater level 8
**A8** = Agent level 8

[What are the meanings of most common abbreviations in Ingress?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/163355/37896)

Comment: This is a great answer