# What are the meanings of most common abbreviations in Ingress?

Tags: ingress, terminology

There are few abbreviations and acronyms in Ingress which might be confusing at first to new players, can you list them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All the abbreviations follow simple rules taking into account the **Rarity**, **Level** and **Name** of an item or thing it represents.

## Items

- **R** - Resonator
- **X**, **XMP** - Burster
- **C**, **PC** - Power Cube
- **U**, **US** - Ultrastrike
- **MUFG** - [MUFG Capsule](http://ingress.wikia.com/wiki/Capsule#MUFG_Capsule)
- **LPC** - [Lawson Power Cube](https://plus.google.com/+Ingress/posts/fYyFU68DmiK)
- Usage: **100XMP6** - 100 level 6 Bursters

## Mods

#### 3 Types of Rarity

- **C** - Common
- **R** - Rare
- **VR** - Very Rare

#### Mod types

- **S** - Shield, **AXA** - AXA Shield
- **HS** - Heat Sink
- **MH** - Multi-Hack
- **LA** - Link Amp
- **FA** - Force Amp
- **T**, **TU** - Turret
- **UL**, **SB** - [SoftBank Ultra Link](http://ingress.wikia.com/wiki/Link_Amp#SoftBank_Ultra_Link)
- Usage: **CMH** / **RMH** / **VRMH** = Common / Rare / Very Rare Multi-Hack

## Miscellaneous

- **L4** - Level 4
- **A8**, **AL8** - (Agent) access level 8
- **P8** - Portal level 8
- **F8** - [Farm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/156994/37896) of level 8 portals (What is [Farm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/156994/37896)?)
- **LTP** - Long Time/Term Portal (Guardian)
- **ETA** - Estimated Time of Arrival
- **F2F** - Face to Face
- **HO** - Hangout (G+ talk)
- Usage: "**1A8** missing for **F8**" or "**1R8** missing for **F8**"
  meaning that 1 Resonator lvl 8 is missing at a farm to make lvl 8 Portals.
- **ENL** - Enlightened
- **RES** - Resistance
- Usage: "Someone go destroy that **ENL F8** in centrum."
  We had **20P8** with **RMH**, **VRS** and Turrets at fully linked **F8**.